# Kotlin: Get Current CoroutineContext.Key without access to the CoroutineScope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to intercept the System.out print statements, and in a multithreaded program, I'm planning on adding these to a map using a `CoroutineContext.Key` as the map key, so I know which coroutine the output belongs to.

My child methods being executed don't have access to the `CoroutineScope` as this was kicked off on a parent method.

I was hoping for a static method along the lines of `CoroutineContext.currentKey` but this doesn't look like it exists.

I've achieved a similar thing in C#, using their `Task.CurrentId`

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `CoroutineContext.Key` is a constant. You need the thread ID, except you don't want that either because you seemingly want to identify the coroutine, which isn't confined to a single thread.

Comment: Exactly. Is there a way around this?
I could switch to using a Thread for my map key, as I can call Thread.currentThread from anywhere. But this is going to be much heavier on performance!

Comment: Why heavier on performance? `currentThread()` is a very cheap call.

Comment: As in I'd have to swap running my asynchronous code inside a new thread, instead of a new coroutine ?

Comment: You said "so I know which thread the output belongs to". But maybe you didn't mean it. I didn't find an obvious key to use for a coroutine.

Comment: Edited. Yeah as 1 coroutine does not = 1 thread, this won't work how I want. I could like I said just start new threads instead of starting new coroutines, but this will be heavier on performance.

Comment: Is your code coroutine-ready? I.e., it makes no blocking calls? Coroutines aren't a drop-in replacement for threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own thread-local variable to keep your own identifier of the coroutine or even directly its saved output and use `ThreadLocal.asContextElement()` extension function to convert it to the coroutine context element. Now, if you start your coroutine with this element, then the specified value of this thread-local variable will be automatically installed into the corresponding thread-local variable as the this coroutine hops from thread to thread. See the following example code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

val myId = ThreadLocal<String>()

// I'm not a suspending function, yet I know what coroutine I work in
fun whereAmI() {
    println("I'm in coroutine '${myId.get()}'")
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch(myId.asContextElement("First")) {
        whereAmI()
    }
    launch(myId.asContextElement("Second")) {
        whereAmI()
    }
}
```